# JMS Point To Point model request and response in jmeter

Tags: jms, jmeter

I just want to see the request and response of jms point to point model in jmeter view result tree listener. I have tried to configure JMS Point To Point model but i could not know the right configuration so please can somebody give me the request and response of JMS Point to Point Model. i will share my JMS point to point model jmeter images with you.

JMS Point To Point Configuration:

[image]

JMS Request :

[image]

JMS Response :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no correct response (since you have [image: warning] and no success [image]). See the sample result tab or the jmeter log for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use version 2.8 of JMeter as many bugs have been fixed since 2.4 (your version)

Then follow jmeter documentation regarding JMS:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point

And part of this for activemq setup:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html